# Launch screens may only have one top level object?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode8, unity-game-engine

Using Unity, I have already created an app for Android devices. Now I am trying to port the app to iPads and iPhones. When building the project (built by Unity in the first place) in Xcode on a Mac machine, I got the following error:

```
Unity-iPhone2
- LaunchScreen-iPad.xib
- Launch screens may only have one top level object, which must be a UIView or a kind of UIViewController.
```

This is the first time I involve myself in Xcode. Any help will be appreciated.